# changing order of unit tests in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

How can I make it so unit tests in Python (using `unittest`) are run in the order in which they are specified in the file?

Comment: It also precludes running the tests in parallel on multicores, or distributed across a cluster. Not a good idea.

Comment: It would matter if 1. You need to debug and want to run the tests in order of increasing complexity and 2. If a small percentage of the tests are computationally heavy, but there are errors that can be spotted with the simpler tests, then having them ordered will make your work much, much faster.

Comment: Sounds like integration tests, not unit tests.

Comment: What is the Python standard for integration testing then?  Is it not...unittest?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can change the default sorting behavior by setting a custom comparison function. In unittest.py you can find the class variable `unittest.TestLoader.sortTestMethodsUsing` which is set to the builtin function `cmp` by default.

For example you can revert the execution order of your tests with doing this:

```
import unittest
unittest.TestLoader.sortTestMethodsUsing = lambda _, x, y: cmp(y, x)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question above

Comment: This *does* answer the question above

Comment: This does seem to do the trick. So is the default order always to run opposite the order of declaration?

Comment: The documentation indicates it depends on the default sorting of strings:--- 
Note that the order in which the various test cases will be run is determined by sorting the test function names with respect to the built-in ordering for strings.

Answer (score 25):

Clever Naming.

```
class Test01_Run_Me_First( unittest.TestCase ):
    def test010_do_this( self ):
        assertTrue( True )
    def test020_do_that( self ):
        etc.
```

Is one way to force a specific order.

Comment: Slightly more clever name is Test010_Run_Me_First so if you decided to push a new one between two, you could.

Comment: Indeed, clever :).

Answer (score 9):

As said above, normally tests in test cases should be tested in any (i.e. random) order.

However, if you do want to order the tests in the test case, apparently it is not trivial.
Tests (method names) are retrieved from test cases using `dir(MyTest)`, which returns a sorted list of members.  You can use a clever (?) hack to order methods by their line numbers.  This will work for one test case:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    ln = lambda f: getattr(MyTestCase, f).im_func.func_code.co_firstlineno
    lncmp = lambda a, b: cmp(ln(a), ln(b))
    loader.sortTestMethodsUsing = lncmp
    unittest.main(testLoader=loader, verbosity=2)
```

Comment: Nice trick, but there's an error in your code.  It should be ``lncomp = lambda _, a, b: cmp(ln(a), ln(b))``

Comment: How can I use this on multiple test cases?

Answer (score 2):

There are also test runners which do that by themselves – I think py.test does it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [proboscis](http://packages.python.org/proboscis/) library as I [mentioned already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095319/unittest-tests-order/14752970#14752970) (please see short description there).

Comment: Tried proboscis... it's worth mentioning that it hijacks the test loading process so if you're using nose, any nose plugins that take advantage of that (e.g. testid) will stop working

Answer (score 1):

The default order is alphabetical. You can put `test_<int>` before every test to specify the order of execution.

Also you can set `unittest.TestLoader.sortTestMethodsUsing = None` to eliminate the sort.

Check out [Unittest Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.sortTestMethodsUsing) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it using PyTest ordering plugin provided [here](http://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.org/en/develop/).

Try `py.test YourModuleName.py -vv` in CLI and the test will run in the order they have appeared in your module.

I did the same thing and works fine for me.

Note: You need to install PyTest package and import it.

Answer (score 0):

hacky way (run this file in pycharm or other unit test runner)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import unittest


def make_suite():
    class Test(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_32(self):
            print "32"
        def test_23(self):
            print "23"

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(Test('test_32'))
    suite.addTest(Test('test_23'))
    return suite

suite = make_suite()

class T(unittest.TestCase):
    counter = 0
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = suite._tests[T.counter](*args, **kwargs)
        T.counter += 1
        return res

for t in suite._tests:
    name = "{}${}".format(t._testMethodName, t.__class__.__name__)
    setattr(T, name, t)
```