# Trying to implement python TestSuite

Tags: python, unit-testing, regression-testing, test-suite, python-unittest

I have two test cases (two different files) that I want to run together in a Test Suite. I can get the tests to run just by running python "normally" but when I select to run a python-unit test it says 0 tests run. Right now I'm just trying to get at least one test to run correectly.

```
import usertest
import configtest # first test
import unittest   # second test

testSuite = unittest.TestSuite()
testResult = unittest.TestResult()
confTest = configtest.ConfigTestCase()
testSuite.addTest(configtest.suite())
test = testSuite.run(testResult)
print testResult.testsRun # prints 1 if run "normally"
```

Here's an example of my test case set up

```
class ConfigTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        ##set up code

    def runTest(self):

        #runs test


def suite():
    """
        Gather all the tests from this module in a test suite.
    """
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(ConfigTestCase))
    return test_suite

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #So you can run tests from this module individually.
    unittest.main()
```

What do I have to do to get this work correctly?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

you want to use a testsuit. So you need not call unittest.main().
Use of testsuit should be like this:

```
#import usertest
#import configtest # first test
import unittest   # second test

class ConfigTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print 'stp'
        ##set up code

    def runTest(self):
        #runs test
        print 'stp'

def suite():
    """
        Gather all the tests from this module in a test suite.
    """
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(ConfigTestCase))
    return test_suite

mySuit=suite()

runner=unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(mySuit)
```

Comment: Thank you, thank worked perfectly for what I needed. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Why on earth do I need to call `unittest.makeSuite` in order to add a test to an *existing* suite?

Comment: In the comments, it's `Gather` or `Gathers`?

Comment: @OlivierPons its gather. Advises the tester

Comment: Ok I thought "Gather all the tests from this module in a test suite." meant "This function gathers all the tests from this module in a test suite." (That's why I thought an `s` should be added but I'm very bad in english, sorry)

Answer (score 9):

All of the code to create a loader and suite is unnecessary. You should write your tests so that they are runnable via test discovery using your favorite test runner. That just means naming your methods in a standard way, putting them in an importable place (or passing a folder containing them to the runner), and inheriting from `unittest.TestCase`. After you've done that, you can use `python -m unittest discover` at the simplest, or a nicer third party runner to discover and then run your tests.

Comment: I'm running into some weird test isolation issues using `unittest discover`, which don't seem to show up if I run a single test file or one TestCase class at a time. I'm not sure if it's a race condition or what, but it's one situation where a defined TestSuite might be helpful.

Comment: @Julian Is there any reason for `suites`? As you said `python -m unittest`  is enough, if proper names are used.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to manually collect `TestCase`s, this is useful: `unittest.loader.findTestCases()`:

```
# Given a module, M, with tests:
mySuite = unittest.loader.findTestCases(M)
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(mySuit)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are referring to running python-unit test against the module that consolidates the two test. It will work if you create test case for that module ie. subclassing `unittest.TestCase` and having a simple test that starts with the word 'test'.

*e.g.*

```
class testall(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_all(self):           
        testSuite = unittest.TestSuite()
        testResult = unittest.TestResult()
        confTest = configtest.ConfigTestCase()
        testSuite.addTest(configtest.suite())
        test = testSuite.run(testResult)
        print testResult.testsRun # prints 1 if run "normally"

if __name__ == "__main__": 
      unittest.main()
```