# How to sort unittest TestCases properly?

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, testing, python-unittest

For instance, I want these to run in the order they appear in the file.

```
import unittest

class Test_MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_run_me_first(self): pass
    def test_2nd_run_me(self):   pass
    def test_and_me_last(self):  pass

class Test_AnotherClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_first(self):        pass
    def test_after_first(self):  pass
    def test_de_last_ding(self): pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Running this gives

```
test_after_first (__main__.Test_AnotherClass) ... ok
test_de_last_ding (__main__.Test_AnotherClass) ... ok
test_first (__main__.Test_AnotherClass) ... ok
test_2nd_run_me (__main__.Test_MyTests) ... ok
test_and_me_last (__main__.Test_MyTests) ... ok
test_run_me_first (__main__.Test_MyTests) ... ok
```

Not what I want.

The answers I've found here on SO after searching all either dance around and avoid the issue by calling / grouping tests or saying

- "don't do it, just write your tests differently" or
- "name your tests lexicographically!"

...except for [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18499093/4532996), which does what I want:

```
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
ln = lambda f: getattr(MyTestCase, f).im_func.func_code.co_firstlineno
lncmp = lambda a, b: cmp(ln(a), ln(b))
loader.sortTestMethodsUsing = lncmp
unittest.main(testLoader=loader, verbosity=2)
```

but only for one TestCase class, and only in Python 2.

I want to run all my Python 3 `unittest.TestCase` subclasses, and I'd like to be able to specify the exact algorithm to use for ordering.

Can I do this in `unittest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>After doing a *lot* of research, aided greatly by SO and Python's `help` and not at all by unittest's documentation, I got the answer *I* initially wanted so I figured I'd write this up to help others, because this is a fair (and apparently common) request.</sup>

---

To run a specific test case, we need to make a new `TestSuite` for that TestCase. [Let's do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011091/trying-to-implement-python-testsuite) for any number of TestCases:

```
def suiteFactory(*testcases):

    ln    = lambda f: getattr(tc, f).__code__.co_firstlineno
    lncmp = lambda a, b: ln(a) - ln(b)

    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    for tc in testcases:
        test_suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(tc, sortUsing=lncmp))

    return test_suite
```

It's pleasingly simple:

1. Define a function to get a function's line number.
   In Python 3, the attribute we're after changed from `func.im_func.func_code.co_firstlineno` to `func.__code__.co_firstlineno`, which you can see using `dir(anyFunction)`.
2. Define a function to sort two arguments based on `cmp`ing their line numbers. `cmp` isn't in Python 3 on account of People Can Do Math, so I've just done exactly what it did in the interest of readability.
3. Make a `new` blank `TestSuite()`, and give it a TestCase or ten, then tell it to sort that TestCase's methods using point #2: `cmp`ing their line numbers.

---

Now we need to sort the file's TestCase subclasses.

To do this, we can look at the `globals()` and their attributes.

```
def caseFactory():

    from inspect import findsource

    g = globals().copy()

    cases = [
        g[obj] for obj in g
            if obj.startswith("Test")
            and issubclass(g[obj], unittest.TestCase)
    ]

    ordered_cases = sorted(cases, key=lambda f: findsource(f)[1])

    return ordered_cases
```

This will just get all the subclasses of `unittest.TestCase` that begin with `Test`, or any naming convention you prefer, and then sort them by their line number: `findsource(object)` returns source code, and line number as index 1, which is what we care about.

---

To wrap it into something we can use:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cases = suiteFactory(*caseFactory())
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
    runner.run(cases)
```

<s>This *does* compartmentalise the output, but probably a good thing if the lowest-level tests are at the top (or bottom, or somewhere) in the file, and should run *before* the higher-level tests.</s>

So the full output is then:

```
test_run_me_first (__main__.Test_MyTests) ... ok
test_2nd_run_me (__main__.Test_MyTests) ... ok
test_and_me_last (__main__.Test_MyTests) ... ok
test_first (__main__.Test_AnotherClass) ... ok
test_after_first (__main__.Test_AnotherClass) ... ok
test_de_last_ding (__main__.Test_AnotherClass) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

**Success!**

---

You can find a more interesting version of this on [Github gist.](https://gist.github.com/catb0t/304ececa6c55f6e3788d)

Comment: Somewhat hard to read. Would it be better if there is mainly a complete small but full example in row. And maybe just sub-class a `TestLoader` (`loadTestsFromTestCase` and `loadTestsFromModule`), whose instance can be simply be passed to unittest.main() or not  - and we have a usual regular test interface.

Comment: Using this code, I got 0 tests running when working with `coverage.py run mytest.py`.