# Custom Python test suite not filtering and running all cases

Tags: python, unit-testing, test-suite

I created a custom test suite to run only one of the test cases but all the test cases are being ran.

```
class TestBlackboxGame(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.public_path = os.path.join('public', 'index.html')
        cls.game_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', cls.public_path))
        assert(os.path.exists(cls.game_path))

        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()

    def test_open_game(self):
        print('Visiting game at ' + self.game_path)
        self.driver.get(self.game_path)
        self.assertTrue('Wheel' == self.driver.title)

    def test_selenium_start_with_bing(self):
        self.driver.get("http://www.bing.com")    
        inputElement = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        inputElement.send_keys("cheese!")
        inputElement.submit()
        self.assertTrue('cheese' in self.driver.title)

def testsuite_open_game():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestBlackboxGame("test_open_game"))
    return suite

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(failfast=True)
    runner.run(testsuite_open_game())
```

In my suite I only added the test case "test_open_game" but it is running both cases including going to Bing and searching. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the code was doing what it is suppose to do. I am using Pycharm and didn't notice that Pycharm was running the script as Unittests. When Pycharm run this script it bypasses my main and run all the test cases regardless.

Comment: so. how did you make it run as a single test?

Comment: You can right click on the test (function) you want to run and Pycharm will give you the option to run that test only.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011091/trying-to-implement-python-testsuite#12011486) answer.

Seems like when you add a TestCase to a suite, you're adding all of its tests. If you wanna run just one test, split into two test cases.

Comment: Oh so `class TestBlackboxGame` is one TestCase? My understanding was each method in the TestBlackboxGame was a single TestCase, except for the setup and teardowns.

Comment: It turn out that the code is doing what it is suppose to. Instead I am an idiot and was running this in Pycharm and it recognize that it is Unittests and runs all of it, effectively by passing my main.