# Remove/overwrite import

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm trying to set up a grading script for an intro CS class using `unittest`.  Essentially, students submit a python file `student.py`, which has some number of functions in it that are generally interdependent (meaning that `func3()` may use `func1()` in it's computations).

I'm writing unit tests for each method by comparing the output of `student.func1` to the output of `correct.func1`, a method that's known to be the correct implementation (from a file `correct.py`).

As an example, say that `func2` uses `func1` in it's computation.
So, either by default or upon `student.func1` failing some test, I want to overwrite `student.func1` with `correct.func1`, so `student.func2` uses a known correct implementation (and therefore isn't just wrong by default).  How could I go about doing that?  It seems like the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` are similar to what I want, but I don't know how to "unimport" modules in python, and haven't found any resources about it so far.

I'm interested in both the case where `student.py` contains classes, and `func1`,`func2` are methods of a specific class, and when `func1` and `func2` are just defined generically within `student.py`.

Comment: I'd argue that replacing wrong functions with correct ones is a bad move in the first place. If `func2` relies on `func1` and `func1` is broken in a way that breaks `func2`, then the students should have noticed that `func2` was broken in testing. Similarly, if they misinterpreted the spec for `func1` and noticed it too late, but all their other functions work with the incorrect `func1` behavior, they shouldn't get points docked on everything because you swapped out their `func1` for something their other functions didn't expect.

Comment: @user2357112 I agree it's not a perfect idea, I just thought of doing it as our current debugging method for finding errors is to replace broken code with known working code until we find out what of theirs didn't work.  Additionally, this script isn't for assigning grades at all, only to assist with hand grading (so if they pass all tests, there's a good indication everything is perfect, if only `func7` fails, maybe look there first, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to import `student` into your module, then catch an `AssertionError` if a test fails, and replace the bad code inside the student module with your own good code:

```
import student

import unittest

def safe_f1():
    print("Safe f1")
    return 1

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_f1(self):
        try:
            self.assertEqual(student.func1(), 1)
        except AssertionError:
            student.func1 = safe_f1
            raise


    def test_f2(self):
        self.assertEqual(student.func2(), 2)
```

Here's a dummy student.py that fails/works:

```
def func1():
    print("Bad f1")
    return 2

def func2():
    return func1() + 1
    return 2
```

When I run this, I get:

```
$ python -m unittest test.py
Bad f1
FSafe f1
.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_f1 (test.TestSomething)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/austin/Code/so/test.py", line 13, in test_f1
    self.assertEqual(student.func1(), 1)
AssertionError: 2 != 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Doesn't work; the other functions will still use the original `func1`.

Comment: You'd have to `import student` and `student.func1 = correct.func1`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I glossed over the part where it's the student code calling func1.

Comment: Okay, better version.

Comment: Will the `raise`'d exception still be logged by `unittest`?

Comment: I don't think unittest actually makes any guarantees about test execution order, which this seems to rely on.

Comment: @user2357112 although it appears I could make them a [TestSuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387299/python-unittest-testcase-execution-order) potentially.

Comment: Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html?highlight=unittest#organizing-test-code), "The order in which the various tests will be run is determined by sorting the test method names with respect to the built-in ordering for strings."

Comment: @AustinHastings: Huh, so it's actually documented. Weird decision. Notably, it's not declaration order, and `test_f10` comes before `test_f2`.

Comment: There are some order-specifying approaches in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387299/python-unittest-testcase-execution-order?noredirect=1&lq=1)