# How to run unittest test cases in the order they are declared

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I fully realize that the order of unit tests should not matter. But these unit tests are as much for instructional use as for actual unit testing, so I would like the test output to match up with the test case source code.

I see that there is a way to set the sort order by setting the `sortTestMethodsUsing` attribute on the test loader. The default is a simple `cmp()` call to lexically compare names. So I tried writing a `cmp`-like function that would take two names, find their declaration line numbers and them return the `cmp()`-equivalent of them:

```
import unittest

class TestCaseB(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        print("running test case B")

class TestCaseA(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        print("running test case A")

import inspect
def get_decl_line_no(cls_name):
    cls = globals()[cls_name]
    return inspect.getsourcelines(cls)[1]

def sgn(x):
    return -1 if x < 0 else 1 if x > 0 else 0

def cmp_class_names_by_decl_order(cls_a, cls_b):
    a = get_decl_line_no(cls_a)
    b = get_decl_line_no(cls_b)
    return sgn(a - b)

unittest.defaultTestLoader.sortTestMethodsUsing = cmp_class_names_by_decl_order
unittest.main()
```

When I run this, I get this output:

```
running test case A
.running test case B
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

indicating that the test cases are not running in the declaration order.

My sort function is just not being called, so I suspect that main() is building a new test loader, which is wiping out my sort function.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem? The code you've posted doesn't include any tests, so it's not going to need to sort any tests.

Comment: (If this *is* the code you ran, then there's your answer: it's not sorting anything because there's nothing to sort.)

Comment: BTW, I guess this is a Python2 project right? As there is no `cmp` in Python3.

Comment: Actually it is a library module that tries to maintain compatibility with Py2.6 thru 3.latest. I forgot that Py3 no longer has `cmp()` - thanks for the catch.

Comment: If you have more than one methods in a class, you will get an exception. And then you will know why.

Comment: I just added a method to TestCaseA - no exception (I have removed the offending cmp() call, see edits). What insight was I supposed to gain from this?

Comment: As @user2357112 has said, it is used to sort methods in **one** class. If you just have only one method, it won't be called at all. But if you have more than one methods, you should meet an exception telling you that `KeyError: 'xxx'` because in global scope there is no `xxx`, that's in the scope of a class.

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430378/5588279) is a related answer, I think it may help you if you really want to sort classes instead of methods.

Comment: Most constructive comment so far, see my self-answer for a working solution.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50283484/6243352) seems like a good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to create a TestSuite explicitly, instead of letting unittest.main() follow all its default test discovery and ordering behavior. Here's how I got it to work:

```
import unittest

class TestCaseB(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        print("running test case B")

class TestCaseA(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        print("running test case A")


import inspect
def get_decl_line_no(cls):
    return inspect.getsourcelines(cls)[1]

# get all test cases defined in this module
test_case_classes = list(filter(lambda c: c.__name__ in globals(), 
                                unittest.TestCase.__subclasses__()))

# sort them by decl line no
test_case_classes.sort(key=get_decl_line_no)

# make into a suite and run it
suite = unittest.TestSuite(cls() for cls in test_case_classes)
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

This gives the desired output:

```
running test case B
.running test case A
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

It is important to note that the test method in each class must be named `runTest`.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually build a TestSuite where your TestCases and all tests inside them run by line number:

```py
# Python 3.8.3
import unittest
import sys
import inspect


def isTestClass(x):
    return inspect.isclass(x) and issubclass(x, unittest.TestCase)


def isTestFunction(x):
    return inspect.isfunction(x) and x.__name__.startswith("test")


class TestB(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_B(self):
        print("Running test_B")
        self.assertEqual((2+2), 4)

    def test_A(self):
        print("Running test_A")
        self.assertEqual((2+2), 4)

    def setUpClass():
        print("TestB Class Setup")


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_A(self):
        print("Running test_A")
        self.assertEqual((2+2), 4)

    def test_B(self):
        print("Running test_B")
        self.assertEqual((2+2), 4)

    def setUpClass():
        print("TestA Class Setup")


def suite():

    # get current module object
    module = sys.modules[__name__]

    # get all test className,class tuples in current module
    testClasses = [
        tup for tup in
        inspect.getmembers(module, isTestClass)
    ]

    # sort classes by line number
    testClasses.sort(key=lambda t: inspect.getsourcelines(t[1])[1])

    testSuite = unittest.TestSuite()

    for testClass in testClasses:
        # get list of testFunctionName,testFunction tuples in current class
        classTests = [
            tup for tup in
            inspect.getmembers(testClass[1], isTestFunction)
        ]

        # sort TestFunctions by line number
        classTests.sort(key=lambda t: inspect.getsourcelines(t[1])[1])

        # create TestCase instances and add to testSuite;
        for test in classTests:
            testSuite.addTest(testClass[1](test[0]))

    return testSuite


if __name__ == '__main__':

    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite())
```

Output:

```
TestB Class Setup
Running test_B
.Running test_A
.TestA Class Setup
Running test_A
.Running test_B
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the name, `sortTestMethodsUsing` is used to sort test *methods*. It is not used to sort classes. (It is not used to sort methods in different classes either; separate classes are handled separately.)

If you had two test methods in the same class, `sortTestMethodsUsing` would be used to determine their order. (At that point, you would get an exception because your function expects class names.)

Comment: While this gives some insight into why the method I tried in my sample code is not going to do what I want, I'm not sure that qualifies as an "answer" to the actual question..