# Execute test case first

Tags: python, python-unittest

I want to run particular test cases for the first time. When we run the test cases file, my particular test cases need to be executed first.

I wrote test cases in python by using the unit-test module.

```
class TestEx(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def test_numbers(self):
        self.assertEqual(3*4, 12)
    def test_strings(self):
        self.assertEqual('a'*3, 'aaa')
    def test_my(self):
        self.assertTrue('in' in 'inspect')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the code it's executed like

```
test_my (__main__.TestEX) ... ok
test_numbers (__main__.TestEx) ... ok
test_strings (__main__.TestEx) ... ok
```

But I want to run `test_numbers` test case first. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate - see discussion here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095319/unittest-tests-order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running unittest with typical test directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure)

Comment: Don't write tests so their order matters. That is very bad practice. Write tests so they are independent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python unittest.TestCase execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387299/python-unittest-testcase-execution-order)