# Django test with setUpTestData doesn't keep changes between tests

Tags: python, django, testing

> classmethod TestCase.setUpTestData()
>
> The class-level atomic block described above allows the creation of initial data at the class level, once for the whole TestCase.
>
> [...]
>
> Be careful not to modify any objects created in setUpTestData() in your test methods. Modifications to in-memory objects from setup work done at the class level will persist between test methods.

Cit. [django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData)

Consider this example:

```
class FoobarTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.post = Post()
        cls.post.stats = {}
        cls.post.save()

    def setUp(self):
        self.post.refresh_from_db()

    def test_foo(self):
        self.post.stats['foo'] = 1
        self.post.save()
        self.assertEquals(self.post.stats, {'foo': 1}) # this should fail

    def test_bar(self): # this run first cause alphabetical order
        self.post.stats['bar'] = 1
        self.post.save()
        self.assertEquals(self.post.stats, {'bar': 1})
```

Since

> Modifications to in-memory objects from setup work done at the class level will persist between test methods

I expect one of the two test methods to fail cause the `post` object will have also a different property and the equality should fail.

But this test pass without problem.

If i force the execution order it actually behave like expected:

```
class FoobarTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.post = Post()
        cls.post.stats = {}
        cls.post.save()

    def setUp(self):
        self.post.refresh_from_db()

    def _foo(self):
        self.post.stats['foo'] = 1
        self.post.save()
        self.assertEquals(self.post.stats, {'foo': 1})

    def _bar(self):
        self.post.stats['bar'] = 1
        self.post.save()
        self.assertEquals(self.post.stats, {'bar': 1})

    def test_foo_bar(self):
        self._foo()
        self._bar() # this fail
```

The question is:

in the first example, are the test methods running in some kind of parallelism? Can they actually fails under some time-related coincidences?

The Django docs about [order in which tests are executed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/#order-in-which-tests-are-executed) doens't talk about test methods.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095319/unittest-tests-order/22317851) i found that the order of test methods can be changed, but is one after another, without parallelism, unless i use `python manage.py test --parallel`.

Comment: To anyone reading this today, Django 3.2+ now make a clean copy of your database, so they are clearly separated https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData

Comment: setUpTestData is called for each test run in case of database with not transaction support e.g. MySQL, this would also explain this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

This is my test, using memory instead of database:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class Post(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = {}

    def refresh_from_db(self):
        pass

    def save(self):
        pass


class FoobarTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.post = Post()
        cls.post.stats = {}

    def setUp(self):
        self.post.refresh_from_db()

    def test_foo(self):
        self.post.stats['foo'] = 1
        self.post.save()
        self.assertEquals(self.post.stats, {'foo': 1})  # this should fail

    def test_bar(self):  # this run first cause alphabetical order
        self.post.stats['bar'] = 1
        self.post.save()
        self.assertEquals(self.post.stats, {'bar': 1})
```

And this is my result:

```
    self.assertEquals(self.post.stats, {'foo': 1})  # this should fail
AssertionError: {'bar': 1, 'foo': 1} != {'foo': 1}
- {'bar': 1, 'foo': 1}
+ {'foo': 1}
```

Changing the method `foo` to `afoo`, the result is as expected:

```
    self.assertEquals(self.post.stats, {'bar': 1})
AssertionError: {'foo': 1, 'bar': 1} != {'bar': 1}
- {'bar': 1, 'foo': 1}
+ {'bar': 1}
```

So maybe this is a database issue somehow?

In your assertion you are checking in-memory objects: if `save` fails, `refresh_from_db` returns the starting empty object, so the next check is passed.

Try getting data back after `save`, then check them.

Comment: In the example if `save` fails i'm expecting to receive an exception. Also in the "real" code i checked this out and there aren't saving errors.

Comment: I think receiving an exception and all this you are experiencing belongs to the model implementation or with some database/driver issue.