# Execution order of python unitests by their declaration

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

I'm using python unittests and selenium and in my code I have one test class with many testcases:

```
class BasicRegression(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=Data.driver)
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(1)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def testcase1_some_stuff(self):
        do_something()

    def testcase2_some_stuff(self):
        do_something()

    def testcase3_some_stuff(self):
        do_something()

    ...

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.close()
        cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The tests are performed alphabetically, i.e. testcase1, testcase2 and testcase3, up to testcase9. Standard. The problem appears with testcase10 and so on, which is executed first.

My question is how can I set their order of execution?

Comment: First: it is usually not a good idea to need a fixed test order, as this means that the tests are depending on each other. If you really need this though, you can just adapt the test names to use `testcase01_...` ... `testcase10_...`. The tests are always executed alphabetically by the default testrunner.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005695/changing-order-of-unit-tests-in-python) about defining the test order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with unit tests are supposed to be independent. So must be [python-unittest](/questions/tagged/python-unittest). Tests executed through `python-unittest` should be designed in such a way that they should be able to be run independently. Pure unit tests offer a benefit that when they fail, they often depicts what exactly went wrong. Still we tend to write functional tests, integration tests, and system tests with the `unittest` framework and these tests won't be feasible to run without ordering them since [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) automates the *Browsing Context*. To achieve the ordering, you at-least need to use a better naming convention for the testnames, as an example: `test_1`, `test_2`, `test_3`, etc and this works because the tests are sorted respect to the built-in ordering for strings.

However, as per your observation the problem appears with `test_10` and so on where sorting order seems to break. As an example, among 3 tests with name as `test_1`, `test_2` and `test_10`, it seems unittest executes `test_10` before `test_2`:

- Code:

  ```
  import unittest

  class Test(unittest.TestCase):

      @classmethod
      def setUp(self):
          print("I'm in setUp")

      def test_1(self):
          print("I'm in test 1")

      def test_2(self):
          print("I'm in test 2")

      def test_10(self):
          print("I'm in test 10")

      @classmethod
      def tearDown(self):
          print("I'm in tearDown")

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Finding files... done.
  Importing test modules ... done.

  I'm in setUp
  I'm in test 1
  I'm in tearDown
  I'm in setUp
  I'm in test 10
  I'm in tearDown
  I'm in setUp
  I'm in test 2
  I'm in tearDown
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

  OK
  ```

---

### Solution

Different solutions were offered in different discussions and some of them are as follows:

- @max in the discussion [Unittest tests order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095319/unittest-tests-order) suggested to set the `sortTestMethodsUsing` to `None` as follows:

  ```
  import unittest
  unittest.TestLoader.sortTestMethodsUsing = None
  ```
- @atomocopter in the discussion [changing order of unit tests in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005695/changing-order-of-unit-tests-in-python) suggested to set the `sortTestMethodsUsing` to some value as follows:

  ```
  import unittest
  unittest.TestLoader.sortTestMethodsUsing = lambda _, x, y: cmp(y, x)
  ```
- @ElmarZander in the discussion [Unittest tests order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095319/unittest-tests-order) suggested to use `nose` and write your testcases as functions (and not as methods of some TestCase derived class) `nose` doesn't fiddle with the order, but uses the order of the functions as defined in the file.
- @Keiji in the discussion [Controlling the order of unittest.TestCases](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122532/controlling-the-order-of-unittest-testcases) mentions:

> sortTestMethodsUsing expects a function like Python 2's `cmp`, which
>   has no equivalent in Python 3 (I went to check if Python 3 had a `<=>`
>   spaceship operator yet, but apparently not; they expect you to rely on
>   separate comparisons for `<` and `==`, which seems much a backwards
>   step...). The function takes two arguments to compare, and must return
>   a negative number if the first is smaller. Notably in *this particular
>   case*, the function may assume that the arguments are never equal, as
>   `unittest` will not put duplicates in its list of test names.
>
> With this in mind, here's the simplest way I found to do it, assuming
>   you only use one TestCase class:

```
def make_orderer():
    order = {}

    def ordered(f):
        order[f.__name__] = len(order)
        return f

    def compare(a, b):
        return [1, -1][order[a] < order[b]]

    return ordered, compare

ordered, compare = make_orderer()
unittest.defaultTestLoader.sortTestMethodsUsing = compare
```

> Then, annotate each test method with `@ordered`:

```
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @ordered
    def test_run_me_first(self):
        pass

    @ordered
    def test_do_this_second(self):
        pass

    @ordered
    def test_the_final_bits(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

> This relies on Python calling annotations in the order the annotated
>   functions appear in the file. As far as I know, this is intended, and
>   I'd be surprised if it changed, but I don't actually know if it's
>   guaranteed behavior. I think this solution will even work in Python 2
>   as well, for those who are unfortunately stuck with it, though I
>   haven't had a chance to test this.
>
> If you have multiple TestCase classes, you'll need to run `ordered,
>   compare = make_orderer()` once per class before the `class`
>   definition, though how this can be used with `sortTestMethodsUsing`
>   will be more tricky and I haven't yet been able to test this either.
>
> For the record, the code I am testing does *not* rely on the test
>   order being fixed - and I fully understand that you shouldn't rely on
>   test order, and this is the reason people use to avoid answering this
>   question. The order of my tests could be randomised and it'd work just
>   as well. However, there is one very good reason I'd like the order to
>   be fixed to the order they're defined in the file: it makes it so much
>   easier to see at a glance *which* tests failed.