# Controlling the order tests are run in Selenium

Tags: python, testing, selenium

Here is my code:

```
class MyTestCase(Base):
    def setUp(self):
        #some code here

    def test_B(self):
        #some code here

    def test_C(self):
        #some code here

    def test_A(self):
        #some code here

    def tearDown(self):
        #some code here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

My problem here is that all my tests are executed in alphabetical order, i.e. test_A is first executed, then test_B and then test_C. I want it to execute in the order I have written, i.e. test_B -> test_C -> test_A.

How do I change the order in which the tests are executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your tests need to be in a specific order I think they should be in the same function, but thats just my opinion, check out [changing order of unit tests in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005695/changing-order-of-unit-tests-in-python)