# Run tests in order Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I am new to Pycharm. I have a python program that consists of 19 classes that all have 1 unit test. When I go to the menu->run->run unit test in test script Pycharm starts at the 6th unit test and not at the first one. When I run this same code in idle it works perfectly.

Is there a way I can configure it to start with the first unit test inside of the first class?

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think this is related to PyCharm. I believe, if you run the tests from Python directly from the command-line, you'll get the same behavior.

Second, I believe this is question is already answered: [changing order of unit tests in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005695/changing-order-of-unit-tests-in-python)