# How to run different script files containing test suites after each other in a specific order

Tags: python, testing, intellij-idea, appium

I'm currently writing tests for a project at work. We use Python 3.6, pytest and Appium with some custom-built functions in IntelliJ IDEA. Right now I have 3 different script files containing test suites for different screens (registration_test, forgot_password_test & login_test). 
How do I run all three after each other in a specific order in a single Appium session?

I've tried to point an IDEA Run Configuration at the tests folder and it does run all the tests but in the wrong order (so they fail). I need to start with the registration, then the forgot password and then the login test.

I also have `noReset` set to `True`

Comment: Have you tried Compound run configuration? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-compound-run-debug-configuration.html#Creating_Compound_Run_Debug_Configuration.xml
It should execute it in the order run configurations are listed.
Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005695/changing-order-of-unit-tests-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Yes but I'm looking for something that makes the tests run after each other, not simultaneously. Is that possible somehow with Compound?